# Any way to set Azure Functions parallelism?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function to call the SpeechToText cognitive server.  I need to ensure that no more than 4 instances of the function spin up.   Is there any way to set the degree of parallelism?

Comment: What is your trigger?

Answer (score 1):

You could try modifying the app's service plan: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview

- Navigate to the function app that you want to update.
- In the Menu, look for the App Service Plan section.
- Select Change App Service plan to start the process.
- Navigate to scale out.
- Enable autoscale.
- Set the desired instance limits.

Comment: It won't always limit the amount of functions running concurrently. You need to make sure you limit them on a single server first...